# Calculate a View once

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view, sql-optimization

I've a problem of sql optimization

I've a View, inside this View I must use another View, now the problem is that I must call this "inner view" more than one time, so this "inner view" is recalculated each time, is there a way to calculate it only the first time?

Comment: How many tables / rows are you working with in the views?  Are there complex calculations?  Most times I can find ways to optimize the underlying views to be more efficient, but if that doesn't work you could try creating an indexed view.

Comment: Check the execution plan.

Comment: Nesting view is going to result in sub-optimal execution plans. It is a recipe for poor performance. Seems to me like you should explore CTEs.